# More efficient way to sum multiple properties?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

So far I have a solution in the vein of:

```
struct MyStruct {
   int propA;
   int propB;
   int propC;
}

/*Extension Method*/
function MyStruct Total(this List<MyStruct> toSum) {
   var sum = new MyStruct();

   toSum.ForEach(x => {
      sum.propA += x.propA;
      sum.propB += x.propB;
      sum.propC += x.propC;
   });

   return sum;
}
```

This iterates over the list once, adding up each property. I feel like there's a more elegant and simple solution that is even potentially more performant, but a better way isn't coming to mind currently. I don't think there's anything really wrong with what I'm doing, but I would like to improve upon it, and I'm hoping someone will be able to help me figure out a better way of doing this.

Comment: NB: Use a `foreach` loop rather than `List<T>.ForEach`. [Justification](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: I don't think you'll get more performant than that (other than switching to a `foreach` loop, which the compiler will probably turn into a marginally faster `for` loop). You could write it as 3 calls to `Sum(...)`, which would be marginally terser, but then you'll be iterating over the list 3 times.

Comment: Applying what said @canton7, I don't think the code can be improved. It seems to be fine as-is.

Comment: Well, we can't tell you what's "more elegant", and that's about as "simple" as it gets. Hard to say what's "better" too.

Comment: It will be linear time with a low constant factor anyway. `for` loops are faster than `foreach` loops (and you're already implicitly doing that with `foreach`), so they might be slightly faster. That requires benchmarking and depends on a lot of things.

Comment: If you're looking for a more efficient way to do that, are you facing a *real* performance issue or a *theoretical* one?

Comment: The given example has microscopic scale and at this scale the elegance and performance start contradicting with each other, so I'm afraid you have to choose what you prefer more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can already sum around 70M of your structs per second in my machine, which is pretty good if you ask me. Anonymous delegates have a cost though, because they cannot be inlined. So replacing `List.ForEach` with a plain vanilla loop makes your code 2x faster (160M structs per second).

```
public static MyStruct Total(this List<MyStruct> source)
{
    var sum = new MyStruct();
    var count = source.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var x = source[i];
        sum.PropA += x.PropA;
        sum.PropB += x.PropB;
        sum.PropC += x.PropC;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Using parallelism speeds up the execution by another 1.5x. Now you are summing 240M structs per second, but you are using 3 cores of the machine instead of one.

```
public static MyStruct Total(this List<MyStruct> source)
{
    var locker = new object();
    var sum = new MyStruct();
    var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, source.Count), options,
        localInit: () => new MyStruct(), body: (range, state, local) =>
    {
        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
        {
            var x = source[i];
            local.PropA += x.PropA;
            local.PropB += x.PropB;
            local.PropC += x.PropC;
        }
        return local;
    }, localFinally: (localSum) =>
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            sum.PropA += localSum.PropA;
            sum.PropB += localSum.PropB;
            sum.PropC += localSum.PropC;
        }
    });
    return sum;
}
```

You can achieve the performance of parallel code using only one core, by using [`Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1)s, [`Vector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1)s and tricky memory alignments. This requires .NET Core, and also to pass as argument an array instead of a list:

```
public static MyStruct Total(this MyStruct[] source)
{
    Debug.Assert(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)) == 12);
    var span = new ReadOnlySpan<MyStruct>(source);
    var intSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<MyStruct, int>(span);
    var sum = new Vector<int>(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < span.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var vector = new Vector<int>(intSpan.Slice(i * 3, 4));
        sum += vector;
    }
    // The last one must be added separately
    sum += new Vector<int>(new int[] {
        source[^1].PropA, source[^1].PropB, source[^1].PropC, 0 });
    return new MyStruct() { PropA = sum[0], PropB = sum[1], PropC = sum[2] };
}
```

Here the `Vector` struct is under-utilized, since only three of the four available `int` slots are used (the fourth is discarded). You should also check the property [`Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated) before entering this code path, because you'll get bad performance if the system does not support Single-Instruction-Multiple-Data (SIMD) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution to using a `for` or `foreach`, which are likely going to be the top performers, you can go with a LINQ solution using the `Aggregate` extension method.

```
public static MyStruct Total(this IEnumerable<MyStruct> toSum)
    => toSum?.Aggregate(new MyStruct(), (acc, elem) =>
        {
            acc.propA += elem.propA;
            acc.propB += elem.propB;
            acc.propC += elem.propC;
            return acc;
        }) ?? new MyStruct();
```

This will fold each element over your accumulator and return the populated accumulator. If the collection is null or empty you will get back an empty instance of MyStruct.

Whether you consider this to be more elegant is likely a matter of taste.